# R graph Poisson distribution and Negative Binomial

Tags: r, graph, poisson

I have some data called y. I must know if they fit either a Poisson or a Negative Binomial distribution.
I would like to have a graph with the density of y, the Poisson density of parameter \lambda = 2.98 and a Negative Binomial Distribution of parameters (\mu = 2.98 and sigma = -1.14).
Basically, I would like to have this graph :
[image]

Does anyone know how I can have it ?

The only thing I know is how to graph the density of y :

```
plot(density(table(y)))
```

Comment: I think you got something wrong with your parameters. Lambda is normally an integer (for the Poisson distribution), and the negative binomial has only one parameter (p).

That said, you can generate the densities you need with `dnbinom()` and `dpois()`. For the density that you have observed, it's just `density(y)`.

Comment: That's true thank you! The parameter of my negative binomial is only 2.98

Comment: The realizations from the poisson distribution are integers, but `lambda` (the mean) can be any non-negative real number.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `geom_density()` from `ggplot2` in next way. Here an example using simulated data. The advice from **@Ben** is pretty useful:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#Data
df <- data.frame(VPoisson=rpois(1000,lambda = 2.98),
                 VNeg=rnbinom(1000,mu = 2.98,size=3),
                 Sample=rnorm(1000))
#Code
df %>% pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=value,color=name))+
  geom_density()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you!!!! That is exactly what i wanted!